# Vertical Align Link in Bootstrap Button Toolbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is really nit picky, but I want to align the link with the baseline of the buttons in this example.  This has something to do with floats because if I disable the float left on `.btn-toolbar .btn-group`, the link text baseline will align with the baseline of the text in the buttons.  I have tried a variety of things like `vertical-align: middle;` and `position: relative;` without success.

**How do I vertically align the link text to have the same baseline as the button text?**

---

### The problem

[image]

### What I want

[image]

### Code

```
  <div class="btn-toolbar clearfix" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups"> 
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="First group"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">3</button> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">4</button> 
    </div> 
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Second group"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">5</button> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">6</button> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">7</button> 
    </div> 
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <a href="#">Super helpful link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group" aria-label="Third group"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">8</button> 
    </div> 
  </div>
```

### Plunk

[Here is a sample Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Sbe8r?p=preview)

Comment: [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is used on table cells and [`position:relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) pulls items out of the document flow. Neither is what you need. As others have pointed out what you will need is [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/RPGdmqAOKbGCZ4z5FZmU?p=preview

`<a href="#" style="line-height: 2.3;">Super helpful link</a>`

Adding some line height will solve your problem.

second thing

- Use **height and line-height in px** for more better

In your case use this
    `line-height: 34px;`
    `height: 34px;`

Comment: This works.  Thank you.  I will upvote but not mark as the answer yet because I wonder if there is a more graceful way to do it?  Let me know if you think of any other answers!  Thanks :)